# When insert my json file in LottieAnimationView a "error null object reference" occurred (Android)

Tags: android, json, animation

I try to use lottie for insert After Effects animation into my application in Android.

I export my After Effects file into .json using Bodybovin, and then insert this to my project.

This is the library version:

```
dependencies {  
   compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:1.5.3'
}
```

I use this code:

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/animation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:lottie_fileName="myAnimation.json"   // This is my file
    app:lottie_loop="true"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"/>
```

When run my application and go on the page with my animation, this error occured:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
```

Into the library called "Lottie" i found this:

```
private static void parseLayers(JSONObject json, LottieComposition composition) {
   JSONArray jsonLayers = json.optJSONArray("layers");
   int length = jsonLayers.length();
   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
     Layer layer = Layer.Factory.newInstance(jsonLayers.optJSONObject(i), composition);
     addLayer(composition.layers, composition.layerMap, layer);
   }
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Check your json file before send it to the method `parseLayers(JSONObject json, LottieComposition composition)`

---

Your error should be here:

```
private static void parseLayers(JSONObject json, LottieComposition composition) {
   JSONArray jsonLayers = json.optJSONArray("layers");
   int length = jsonLayers.length(); // ************** HERE **************
   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
     Layer layer = Layer.Factory.newInstance(jsonLayers.optJSONObject(i), composition);
     addLayer(composition.layers, composition.layerMap, layer);
   }
}
```

In that moment the object `jsonLayers` is null. You can add a simple if or a try catch to manage the error:

```
private static void parseLayers(JSONObject json, LottieComposition composition) {
   JSONArray jsonLayers = json.optJSONArray("layers");
   if(jsonLayers != null){
       int length = jsonLayers.length();
       for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
           Layer layer = Layer.Factory.newInstance(jsonLayers.optJSONObject(i), composition);
           addLayer(composition.layers, composition.layerMap, layer);
       }
    } else {
        // manage the error
    }
}
```

or

```
    private static void parseLayers(JSONObject json, LottieComposition composition) {
       JSONArray jsonLayers = json.optJSONArray("layers");
       try{
           int length = jsonLayers.length();
           for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
               Layer layer = Layer.Factory.newInstance(jsonLayers.optJSONObject(i), composition);
               addLayer(composition.layers, composition.layerMap, layer);
           }
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            // manage the error
        }
    }
```

---

This error is not related to your animation:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
```

This error means that you are trying to use the method `lenght()` on a `JSONArray` object and this object is `null`.

Please copy your full error report and check in which line the error occurs.

It will be something like:

```
JSONArray ja = getJson(); // getJson() return null for any reason
int lenght = ja.lenght(); // the error occurs because 'ja' is null
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have updated my questions.

Comment: I will try to do a pull request to this library. But I think that the problem is about my file .json, I'm not sure that this library covers all cases of the animation on this file.

Comment: Yes, check your json file. If this code is from a library, you should check your json before sending it to the method.